# What is categorized as dependency to be passed to useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When reading the [the official Hooks guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect), it mentioned that **every value referenced inside the effect function should also appear in the dependencies array**. My question is, what are categorized as the dependency? Check the following example from Dan Abramov:

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [count]);

  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
}
```

In this case `count` is passed to the dependency array. However why isn't `setCount` passed as well? To me it is a function dependency too.

More generally, what is categorized as the dependency which should be passed into the dependency array when using `useEffect`?

Comment: dependency in `useEffect()` is some value that could be changed and then invoke the `useEffect()` again, for functions there is another hook called `useCallback()`

Comment: @zb22 does that mean only values should be passed as dependency array to `useEffect`? Functions are passed as dependencies to `useCallback`?

Answer (score 0):

By dependency we are meant to understand values that might change (state or props). `count` is a reference to a number, it changes every time you call `setCount` with a new value. `setCount` on the other hand is a reference to a function that never changes.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, what are categorized as the dependency

Generally, everything that's defined inside the functional component and is used inside the callback passed as the first argument to useEffect.

> In this case count is passed to the dependency array. However why
> isn't setCount passed as well? To me it is a function dependency too.

There's nothing wrong with adding setCount to the dependencies. React will make sure that setCount doesn't change so adding/removing it from the dependencies makes no difference.

> More generally, what is categorized as the dependency which should be
> passed into the dependency array when using useEffect?

Dependencies are added to avoid stale values and also to call the callback function whenever one of the added dependencies change.